# Splitting a single virtual hard disk in VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtual-disk

I created a virtual machine in VMWare Player. I created a 20 GB (max size) virtual hard disk for it and choose "single file" instead of "split into multiple files". Now, whenever I use the VM, the backup program detects change in the file backs up the whole 17 GB (current size) file.

I want to know if there is any way I can split an existing virtual hard disk created by VMWare Player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to migrate the disk to a disk that's already set up in split configuration.

Create a disk with the same or more disk space allocated to it, when creating it make sure that you choose the option to split the disk.

Ensure that the virtual disk being changed does not have any snapshots associated with it.

1. Power off the virtual machine.
2. Open a command prompt with Administrative privileges.
3. Navigate to the product's installation directory.
4. Run this command: `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -r <filepath of original disk> -t 1 <filepath of new disk>`

To determine the location of your existing disk go to **VM > Settings**, click the **Hardware** tab, and select your hard disk. The disk file is listed at the top, on the right side. If no path is provided, then the virtual disk is in the same directory as the configuration file

[Ref: VMware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006898)

Comment: The answer is a bit confusing. The steps that need to be done are 1-4. Everything before that is an overview. I read this and manually created the disk and tried to then execute steps 1-4 which meant the new disk was already made and improperly configured.